# Navigation partial cannot be rendered on application.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

No sure why the navigation partial just won't render. I do have the navigation partial in the shared folder named as "_navigation.html.erb"

I'm using rails 5.1.2, ruby 2.3.1 on a cloud 9 workspace.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpRCo.png)

[Cloud 9 workspace file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKKq.png)

Comment: Can you check again whether you have it correctly like `_navigation.html.erb`?

Comment: Did you try `= render partial: 'shared/navigation'` ?

Comment: Oh gosh that is plain stupid, i wrote it as hml.erb instead of html.erb. Thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your *file name* being **wrong**. It should be `_navigation.html.erb`. Currently you have it like `_navigation.hml.erb`. Changing your file name to `_navigation.html.erb` should fix your problem.